# Guava CacheLoader with multiple keys each with its own refreshAfterWrite

Tags: java, caching, guava

I currently have a `CacheLoader`

```
public class TransactionsDetailsCache extends CacheLoader<String, Transactions> {

    private final Client client;

    private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    public TransactionsDetailsCache(Client client) {
        this.client = checkNotNull(client);
    }

    @Override
    public Transactions load(String s) {
        return getTransactionsDetails(client);
    }

    // refreshing here by calling load
    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<Transactions> reload(String key, Transactions oldValue) {
        ListenableFutureTask<Transactions> task = ListenableFutureTask.create(() -> load(key));
        executor.execute(task);
        return task;
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    protected Transactions getTransactionsDetails(Client Client) {
        Response response = client.getTransactions();

        final Set<TransactionDetails> deniedTransactions = response.stream()
                .filter(transaction -> "denied".equalsIgnoreCase(transaction.getType()))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        final Set<TransactionDetails> allowedTransactions = response.stream()
                .filter(transaction -> "allowed".equalsIgnoreCase(transaction.getType()))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        return new Transactions(allowedTransactions, deniedTransactions);
    }
}
```

and injecting it using

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public LoadingCache<String, Transactions> provideTransactionsDetails(Client client) {
    return CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .refreshAfterWrite(Duration.ofMinutes(60))
            .build(new TransactionsDetailsCache(client);
}
```

and my `Transactions` looks like

```
@Data
public class Transactions {
    Set<TransactionDetails> allowedTransactions;
    Set<TransactionDetails> deniedTransactions;
}
```

I am currently using the following to get `Transactions` object.

```
transactions = cache.get("transactions");
```

I want to set different `refreshAfterWrite` times to `allowedTransactions` and `deniedTransactions` and get them using same cache. Is this possible using a single CacheLoader ? I see that a `key` can be passed to reload method but not sure how to use it and `refreshAfterWrite` different for each key.

```
allowedTransactions = cache.get("allowedTransactions");
deniedTransactions = cache.get("deniedTransactions");
```

I want cache with key `allowedTransactions` to reload after 1 hour, and with key `deniedTransactions` to reload after 5 minutes.

I do not want to have different caches because both `allowedTransactions` and `deniedTransactions` are received from single API call and want them to be in single cache. I feel like this can be achieved with using different `key`, but not sure how to get expiry for each key, time of last refresh is not stored anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not supported by Guava.  (I don't believe it's even supported by Caffeine, which is a more advanced replacement for Guava's cache.)

Comment: Correct, though it is on the backlog. Feedback on the [api sketch](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/issues/504#issuecomment-1086922055) would be appreciated.